How encode forHandle parameter using YouTube API?
I am trying to request statistics from Youtube channels that have special chars in the name, like FisicaUniversitáriaUSP.
When I use the code below, there is no results in the response, but the channel exists: https://www.youtube.com/c/FisicaUniversit%C3%A1riaUSP
Code in Python 3:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

c = 'FisicaUniversitáriaUSP'
yt = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
req = yt.channels().list(part='statistics', forHandle=c.encode())
resp = req.execute()
print(resp)

I appreciate some help!

You are confusing handles and c ids, see my Stack Overflow answer 75843807 for a solution.

No, I am not confusing handles and ids channels. Unfortunately, YouTube API does not support encoding to allow use special chars, like á, é, í, ó, ú etc, to execute searches.

Try to use the channelId to avoid these encoding mismatch.
If you only have the channel handle name, first try to search for the channel in order to get the channelId:
c = 'channelHandleName'
r = yt.search().list(
    part='snippet',
    q=c,
    type='channel',
    maxResults=1
).execute()

Associated documentation for yt.search().list: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
Then, if it returned results get the first result channelId property to build the request to channels().list:
if req_search_shannels.get('items'):
    channel_id = req_search_shannels['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
    response = yt.channels().list(
        part='statistics',
        id=channel_id
    ).execute()

    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
else:
  print('couldnt find channel', c)

documentation for yt.channels().list parameters:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
If you search for channels providing the channel handle name, it will always return the correct channel first on the list.
